# How to access a VM that's accessible from RDP via Local Machine?

Tags: networking, ssh, cloud, virtual-machine, vpn

I've a company VM that that's accessible via SSH.
But the catch is that I need to use the following approach:

  `My PC (with VPN) -> RDP -> Using SSH -> VM`

 I want to connect with the following approach: 
`My PC (with VPN) -> Using SSH -> VM`
Basically, can I reroute my traffic to remote VM without RDP

Answer (score 0):

You need an open ssh port on your RDP-Host.
That could be a port forward to your VM or you could also start a ssh server on the RDP-Host to be used as ssh-jumpbox.

1. My PC (with VPN) -> Using SSH  -> ( RDP-Host with forwarded port to VM) -> VM

   `ssh myVMuser@myRDPHost`

   You could use `iptables` for that
2. My PC (with VPN) -> Using SSH -> RDP-Host with ssh-server -> VM

   `ssh myVMuser@myVM -o ProxyJump=myRDPUser@myRDPHost`

   Just use `systemctl status ssh.service` and add your public key